# Complex numbers in Euler's rule

Tags: complex-numbers, constants

I know that $\sin(ix) = \sinh(x)$ based on manipulation of Euler's rule. However if I introduce a constant $a$, is this relation correct?

$\sin(iax)=i\sin(ax)$

Comment: You have a typo (missing an "h")and presumably intended to ask about $\sin(iax)=i\sinh(ax)$.  Just use $ax$ rather than $x$ in your original expression

Answer (score 4):

When we say that
$$
\sin(ix) = i\sinh(x)
$$
in this context that means that the two sides are equal *no matter* what complex number we put instead of $x$. When you write $ax$ instead of $x$, that is just another number, and equality still holds.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Given that:
$\sinh(x) = \frac{(e^x - e^{-x})}2$ ,
$$\sinh(iax) = \frac{e^{iax} - e^{-iax}}2$$
And therefore:

$$\sinh(iax)= \frac{1}{2}(\cos(ax) + i\sin(ax) $$
                         $$- \cos(ax) + i\sin(ax))$$
            $$  = 2i\frac{\sin(ax)}2 = i\sin(ax)$$

Comment: Yes, this site will eat (single) carriage returns, and any space after the first. Check [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a brief math formatting guide. And welcome to the site.

Comment: Thanks! Also hard because I was on mobile.